# Deploy Keycloak in HA mode in Azure

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, keycloak

I am trying to deploy a keycloak in standalone HA mode in azure.  I understand that keycloak requires multicast to support node clustering.  How do i configure keycloak to run in HA mode in Azure when multicast is not available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TCPPING for cluster discovery.

Refer to this post: [Keycloak(Wildfly/Infinispan) in HA mode - issue in detecting other machines in the cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673917/keycloakwildfly-infinispan-in-ha-mode-issue-in-detecting-other-machines-in-t/62752016#62752016)

- Change your default stack to `TCP`.
- Remove `MPING` from your configuration and add the following:

```xml
<protocol type="TCPPING">
    <property name="initial_hosts">{IP}[7600]</property>
    <property name="num_initial_members">2</property>
    <property name="port_range">0</property>
    <property name="timeout">2000</property>
</protocol>
```

- Make sure that jgroups-tcp and jgroups-tcp-fd is listening to public interface, and not private interface. These properties are in standalone/configurations/standalone-ha.xml.
- While starting the the instances of your cluster via bin/standalone.sh | bin/standalone.bat make sure you pass `-b <public interface IP>` and not `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces). To find the public interface IP, run the following command:

`ifconfig eth0 | grep -i mask | awk '{print $2}'| cut -f2 -d:`

- When you start the first instance (should be the instance you passed in initial_hosts property; you can try `telnet <IP> 7600` to test if your TCPPING is working or not. It should work for cluster discovery.