# Keycloak(Wildfly/Infinispan) in HA mode - issue in detecting other machines in the cluster

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, high-availability, infinispan

As a result, when I put the machines under an ELB, the login doesn't work.
I have tried TCP and UDP for IP casting. Tried using TCPPING instead of MPING (although not sure whether I used them correctly).
Infinispan is being used for distributed caching.
Here is the default configuration, followed by the changes I had made:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:7.0">
    <channels default="tcp">
        <channel name="ee" stack="udp" cluster="ejb"/>
    </channels>
    <stacks>
        <stack name="udp">
            <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-udp"/>
            <protocol type="PING"/>
            <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
            <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="UFC"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
        </stack>
        <stack name="tcp">
            <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
            <socket-protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
             <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
            <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
            <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
            <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
            <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
            <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
            <protocol type="MFC"/>
            <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
        </stack>
    </stacks>
</subsystem>
```

Changed to TCP, and in TCP stack, removed MPING to add TCPPING:

```
<transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
    <protocol type="TCPPING">
    <property name="initial_hosts"><IP of VM1>[7600],<IP of VM2>[7600]</property>
    <property name="port_range">0</property>
</protocol>
```

How can I further debug the deployment?

Comment: Any errors in the logs?
Can you ping VM2 from VM1 and vice-versa?
Check if your firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: No error in the logs.
Yes, I can ping VM2 from VM1 and vice-versa.
What else can I check?

Comment: I don't spot any error in your config. Infinispan logs the IP address so you can search in the logs for a line like this `ISPN000079: Channel clustered local address is <hostname>, physical addresses are [127.0.0.1:7600]`. Check if the ip:port matches the ones you configured.

Comment: @pruivo I answered mentioning how I debugged it. Do you have anything to add on to it, plz edit my answer. 

There aren't many resources relating to this issue. Can be helpful to the community in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I debugged it:

- Make sure that `jgroups-tcp` and `jgroups-tcp-fd` is listening to public interface, and not private interface. These properties are in `standalone/configurations/standalone-ha.xml`.
- While starting the the instances of your cluster via `bin/standalone.sh | bin/standalone.bat` make sure you pass `-b <public interface IP>` and not `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces). To find the public interface IP, run the following command:

  `ifconfig eth0 | grep -i mask | awk '{print $2}'| cut -f2 -d:`
- When you start the first instance (should be the instance you passed in `initial_hosts` property; you can try `telnet <IP> 7600` to test if your TCPPING is working or not. It should work for cluster discovery.